# Why is IndexError thrown when I try to index a numpy ndarray with another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have a 5 dimensional ndarray called `self.q_table`. I've got a regular array, the length of which is 4. When I try to find out the maximum value in that row like this...

```
max = np.max(self.q_table[regular_array])
```

...I get an IndexError, even though the elements of `regular_array` are smaller than the dimensions of `q_table`.

I tried to alter the dimensions of both arrays, but it didn't get better.

Edit:

The error is `IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10`

Numpy is imported as np, and the last line in this sample throws the error.

```
class AgentBase:
def __init__(self, observation_space):
    OBSERVATION_SPACE_RESOLUTION = [10, 15, 15, 15]
    self.q_table = np.zeros([*OBSERVATION_SPACE_RESOLUTION, 4])
    max_val = np.max(self.q_table[self.quantize_state(observation_space, [-150, 100, 3, 3])])
    print(max_val)

@staticmethod
def quantize_state(observation_space, state):
    state_quantized = np.zeros(len(state))
    lin_spaces = []
    for i in range(len(observation_space)):
        lin_spaces.append(np.linspace(observation_space[i][0], observation_space[i][1],
                                     OBSERVATION_SPACE_RESOLUTION[i] - 1, dtype=int))
    for i in range(len(lin_spaces)):
        state_quantized[i] = np.digitize(state[i], lin_spaces[i])
    return state_quantized.astype(int)
```

`self.observation_space` is a parameter with the following values:
[image]

Comment: Can you turn this into a small working example? That helps clarify the problem and is the basis for answers. This appears to be in an instance method, but the example doesn't have to go that far.

Comment: Come on - provide us with some real information!  Like the full text of the error?  Info on the arrays would also help, such as `shape` and `dtype`.  Is this `regular_array` supposed to have one value per dimension, or 4 values on one dimension?  Maybe you should be using a tuple rather than an array (that's just a guess based on a poorly  worded description).

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'll edit the post accordingly.

Comment: Why is it unclear to you why index 11 is out of bounds for an array with size 10?

Comment: @mkrieger1 because the ndarray is shaped [10, 15, 15, 15, 4], and the array I try to index it with is [3, 7, 11, 11]. What I don't understand is why 11 is compared to 10, shouldn't it be 3, as it's the first element of the array? I'm pretty unfamiliar with numpy though, it is very possible that I have misunderstood something.

Comment: By "regular array", do you mean Python’s built-in list type?

Comment: Yeah, that, sorry. Look at the code sample though, you can even run it with the given observation_space values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you index an ndarray with a list (or, to quote the numpy docs, "a non-tuple sequence object"), you invoke [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), so when you index with `[3,7,11,11]` it tries to apply all those values to the first dimension.

I agree with @hpaulj’s comment that you may want to index with a tuple instead.

Comment: solved it, thanks! I just had to convert the result of quantize_state to tuple